# Trouble understanding what "the intersection is transversal" means

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

So, I'm trying to solve an exercise and among the given facts there is the following claim:

> Let $y_0 \ge 0$ such that the intersection between $\{y=y_0\}$ and
>   $\{f(x,y)=h(y)\}$ is transversal $(*)$

Note that $f \in L^\infty(\Omega \times [0,+\infty))$  and $\Omega$ is a compact manifold in $\mathbb R^2$. About $h$ we only know that is a well defined function.

**QUESTION:**
What information -regarding $h$ or in general- can we obtain from $(*)$?

To be honest, is the first time I hear the term "transversality". Although I found some definitions concerning manifolds and their tangential maps, I'm not able to find the relation between them and my claim (if there is such one). What does $(*)$ imply?

I apologize if my question is a bit blurry but I'm having a really hard time understanding what should $(*)$ yield.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A standard reference is Guillemin and Pollack "Differential Topology". Or just read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics)) on transversality.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I already did but it didn't help me much

Comment: It means that for any point $(x,y_0)$ in the intersection, the tangent spaces to $\{y=y_0\}$ and $\{f(x,y)=h(y)\}$ together span $T_{(x,y_0)}(\Omega\times[0,\infty))$.

Comment: To talk about transversality you will need $f$ and $h$ to be differentiable or piecewise linear or some such.

Comment: @TedShifrin why do I need these conditions you mentioned?

Comment: Before doing any calculations, why not draw pictures? Take two smooth curves in $\mathbb R^2$ and see what there tangents look like, based on  how they can intersect. Then, take two curves that are not smooth (suppose one or both has a cusp at the intersection point) ad see how their tangents look, or if in fact they even have a unique tangent. The idea is that if the two curves are transverse, then 1): their tangents exist at $(x_0,y_0)$ and 2): the tangents "point " in different directions so they span all of $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: @Matematleta I have to admit that this example is quite helpful in order to understand the definitions better. Thanks!

Comment: You need some smoothness or piecewise linear structure to be able to talk about tangent spaces to the curves. In your case, the tangent lines of the two curves at any point of intersection must not be the same.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes...after the comment of Matematleta I realized it. Thanks!

Comment: @kaithkolesidou You're welcome. I am self-studying these topics too. I found [Loring Tu's book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Manifolds-Universitext-Loring-W-ebook/dp/B014P9I1MU) very clear. I am currently about 3/4 through [Lee's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387217529), which is a gem: great explanations, lots of exercises.